# Creating an XML document in Embarcadero RAD Server 10.3

Tags: xml, delphi, rad

I have an endpoint in the RAD Server which generates and returns an XML document.  This code works just fine in a development environment.  However, when I copy the bpl to the production server running on Apache on Windows, it returns a 500 error.
I have figured out that is the code call to NewXMLDocument which is causing the error.  I just don't know why it works on the development server but not on the production server and I don't know how to get any further diagnostic information from the production server.

The code is below and I have removed pieces of code that are not impacting the error.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit:  I was able to get a line further and now it is throwing the 500 error at:
`RootNode := resultDoc.AddChild('root');`

Solved: Found the issue was with MSXML on the server.  Switched to Omnixml as default DOM vendor and everything seems to work.  Thanks everyone.

```
procedure TQResource1.GetIMCansXML(const AContext: TEndpointContext;
  const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
var
  sPlace      : String;
  resultDoc   : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode    : IXMLNODE;
  myStream    : TMemoryStream;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  iNumRows := 0;
  Try
    Try
      SetDBConnection(AContext.User.UserName);
      myStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      sPlace := '2';
      resultDoc := NewXMLDocument;
      sPlace := '3';
      resultDoc.Encoding := 'utf-8';
      resultDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
      sPlace := '4';

      RootNode := resultDoc.AddChild('root');
      resultDoc.SaveToStream(myStream);
      myStream.Position := 0;

    Except
      on e1: exception do
      begin
        raise Exception.Create(e1.Message + ' @ ' + sPlace);
      end;
    End;

  Finally
    AResponse.Body.SetStream(myStream, 'application/xml', True);
    CoUninitialize;
  End;

end;
```

Comment: what OS are you running on the prod server? try making a small console application that calls `NewXMLDocument` and run it on the prod server.

Comment: Window Server 2008 RS.  Old, I know, but it is scheduled to be upgraded soon.

Comment: I created a small windows application the also calls the NewXMLDocument method and it does NOT throw an error when run on the server.

Comment: @KenDavis Is `NewXMLDocument()` raising an exception? Also, you need to explicitly set `resultDoc` to `nil` before calling `CoUninitialize()`, otherwise it will get released afterwards, which will cause problems for COM. On a side note, your `except` handler really doesn't need to raise a new `Exception`. It can modify the `Message` of the caught `Exception` and then re-raise it, eg: `on E: Exception do begin E.Message := E.Message + ' @ ' + sPlace; raise; end;`. This way, any type info and extra details of the original exception are not lost.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will make those changes and see if I can get any further.  But to answer your question, no.  No exception is raised.  It works perfectly fine on the development server which is able to return exception information if there is one.  The production server will not return any exception information.  It will only return 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: You say that you have this code in BPL. Have you checked to see if your production server might be missing some other BPL required by this specific BPL that you have present on your development environment?

Comment: @SilverWarior - I have compared the BPLs that seem to be relevant.  xmlrtl260.bpl is there and is the same version.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused in code working with XML. What if it is caused in `EMS.ResourceAPI`? Do you ship relevant BPL's needed for `EMS.ResourceAPI`?

Comment: I believe all the BPL are there.  The API has lots of endpoints.  It is just this one that is creating the XML code.  I have commented out everything until it no longer gave a 500.  
Commenting back in the call to NewXMLDocument caused the 500 error to return.
There could be some other BPL that I am missing, but I believe I have everything that is in the test server.

Comment: what is the actual exception you are getting?

Comment: @whosrdaddy - that is right at the root of the problem.  I don't get an exception.  The endpoint just returns 500 Internal Server Error but doesn't pass along any exception messages.

Comment: Maybe it is Apache that is blocking the exception message from being returned for security purposes?

Comment: Good news, I am making progress.  I decided to drop an actual TXMLDocument on the form rather than creating it dynamically.  It did not solve the problem, but it did allow an exception message to be returned:
"Microsoft MSXML is not installed"
So, now I am headed off that direction.  I will report back.

Comment: Well, I tried to install MS Core Services 6.0 but it told me it is already installed.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if I have the XML services thing fixed, but I am able to get past the NewXMLDocument.  Now, it is giving me a 500 error at the line `RootNode := resultDoc.AddChild('root');`  I am still not able to get any more error information than 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: You can remove the msxml dependency by setting Omnixml as default DOM vendor.

Comment: @whosrdaddy, that is what I ended up doing.  nothing I did could get the MSXML to work correctly.  Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was removing the msxml dependency by setting Omnixml as default DOM vendor.